# figure()-Function from Pyplot throws ValueError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data using python and matplotlib.
For doing Updates on the plot, I'll use the `set_ydata()` function.

I'm using the example Code from [here](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-update-plot/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b-') 

for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(0.5 * x + phase))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

When running the program I get the Error

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

After stepping through the Programm step-by-step, I found out, that this error occurs when the function `plt.figure()` is called. 
What is the matter here?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not throw an error for me. Can you show the full traceback of the error?

Comment: In addition to the full traceback, the versions of python, numpy and matplotlib would be needed, and a description on how/where this code is run.